# Android MediaPlayer.start does not start

Tags: android

I have yet to find an answer to this.

I have a local file (R.raw.Bob); and I am trying to use MediaPlayer to play the file.

Sometimes it plays, sometimes it does not. I have another file which plays seemingly fine every time.

My activity flow is like this: In onCreate I do the following:

```
MediaPlayer mBackground = MediaPlayer.create(MainAct.this, R.raw.background);
mBackground.start(); // Works as expected.
```

Now in a different part of the activity I have the following:

```
MediaPlayer mBob= MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.Bob);
mBob.start();
```

And nothing occurs. I have used Log.i() and the execution goes through the relevant code but the file does not start.

Why does MediaPlayer sometimes work and sometimes does not, and is there a more reliable way of playing sound files?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to start:

```
MediaPlayer mBob = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.Bob);

    mBob.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
        }
    });
```

and this to stop:

```
mBob.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Same outcome, file does not play

Comment: You said it's show exception, can you show it please?

Comment: No exceptions, I said the player.start() line is executed in case people thought it wasn't

Comment: Ah, sorry my wrong, If you can provide full activity code this may help!